# Browserstack: Only one OS option pr. iOS device?

Tags: browserstack

I wish to reproduce an error repported on an **iPad Air 2, iOS 11.2.5** - but I can't seem to change the OS for each device. Why is that, or how do I achieve that?

[image: Selection in browserstack dashboard]

Comment: I am guessing they do not offer this. You may want to connect with their support team to confirm this

Comment: @BountyHunter, you were right - and I got a response from support confirming it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

BrowserStack support gave a very fast and elaborate response:

**No**, it's not currently possible.

**No**, it's not currently in their roadmap.

**But**, they have started offering older devices with latest iOS's - starting with iPhone 6S and 6S Plus (with iOS 11). No plans for doing the same for iPad's currently, but they consider it as a feature request.